# Highlighting Date cells which are older than a week !!!Dash

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I'm trying to colour the dates which are longer than a week ago.
But when I do it, it colours all the dates.

First I tried it before my dash code and it works perfectly

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(list(collection_jobs.find({"1_Date":{'$regex':Date},"2_Color":"red"}, {'_id': False})))

df.columns = ['Date', 'Color', 'Name', 'Description', 'Last Build', 'Last Build Result', 'Last Failed Build', 'Last Successful Build', 'Last Unsuccessful Build']

print(df['Last Successful Build'])
>>>0     05/07/2019 09:48:29
1     15/07/2019 08:35:59
2     12/06/2019 08:21:46
3     06/07/2019 01:25:00
4     13/07/2019 21:55:00
5     13/07/2019 21:30:00
6     11/07/2019 03:49:00
7     13/07/2019 20:22:00
8     15/06/2019 11:42:00
9     11/07/2019 01:37:00

Name: Last Successful Build, dtype: object


df['Last Successful Build'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Last Successful Build'], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

week_ago = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=7)

print("")
print(week_ago)
>>>2019-07-10 11:48:40.377170
print("")
print(df['Last Successful Build'])
>>> 0    2019-07-05 09:48:29
1    2019-07-15 08:35:59
2    2019-06-12 08:21:46
3    2019-07-06 01:25:00
4    2019-07-13 21:55:00
5    2019-07-13 21:30:00
6    2019-07-11 03:49:00
7    2019-07-13 20:22:00
8    2019-06-15 11:42:00
9    2019-07-11 01:37:00

Name: Last Successful Build, dtype: datetime64[ns]
print("")
result = df['Last Successful Build'] < week_ago
print(result)
>>>0      True
1     False
2      True
3      True
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8      True
9     False

Name: Last Successful Build, dtype: bool
```

Here's my code where I filter/colour it

```py
style_data_conditional=[
            {
                'if': {
                    'column_id' : 'Last Successful Build',
                    'filter_query': '{Last Successful Build} < week_ago'
                },
                'backgroundColor': 'white',
                'color': '#ed0909',
            },                             
        ],
```

I expect the output to colour the lines where the result would be true.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fix the problem by making the data in ['Last Successful Build'] like this >>> 2019-07-11
Then for the week_ago, I did this:

```py
week_ago = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=7)
week_agoDate = week_ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

And as of last in the dash code where u make your data table I changed it to this:

```py
style_data_conditional=[
            {
                'if': {
                    'column_id' : 'Last Successful Build',
                    'filter_query': ('{Last Successful Build} <' + week_agoDate)
                },
                'backgroundColor': 'white',
                'color': '#ed0909',
            },                             
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I already have the correct datatypes and if i compare them and print them, the correct ones output as true but for some reason it colours them all.
can somone help ?

```py
dft['Datum'] = pd.to_datetime(dft["Datum"]).dt.date
dft['erledigt am'] = pd.to_datetime(dft["erledigt am"]).dt.date

week_ago = datetime.date.today() - timedelta(days=7)
print(week_ago)
print(dft['Datum'])

res = dft['Datum'] < week_ago

print(res)
```

this is were older dates (print res) are correctly evaluated. Yet here :

```py
style_data_conditional= ( 

{ 
'if': 
  { 'filter_query': '{Datum} < week_ago ',
    'column_id ': 'Datum '
  },
  'backgroundColor ': 'lightcoral ',
},

                          )
```

It colours every cell with a date in that column.